# Oracle - How can I create one insert with multiple values dynamically

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I want to create one INSERT statement with multiple values dynamically like to following example:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (ID, PARENT, NAME, ENABLED) 
VALUES (1, 't1', 'Test1', 1 ), (2, 't2', 'Test2', 1 ), (3, 't3', 'Test3', 1 );
```

Currently I'm working with the following statement, but now I get too many individual statements and this doesn't deliver good performance

```sql
SELECT 'INSERT INTO table_name(ID, PARENT, NAME, ENABLED) ' 
|| 'VALUES ('|| ID ||','''|| PARENT ||''','''|| NAME || ''', '|| ENABLED ||');'
FROM table_name WHERE ID IN (... [inner select] ...);
```

How is it possible to create a loop which attached new values ins a single insert statement like this?

```sql
SELECT 'INSERT INTO table_name (ID, PARENT, NAME, ENABLED)' VALUES

DECLARE
    myValues varchar2(500);
    CURSOR myCur IS SELECT ID, PARENT, NAME, ENABLED FROM table_name;
BEGIN
    FOR values IN myCur LOOP

        IF myCur%ROWCOUNT = 1 THEN
            myValues := '('||values.ID ||', '''|| values.PARENT ||''', '''|| values.NAME ||''', '|| values.ENABLED ||'),';
        ELSE
            myValues := '('||values.ID ||', '''|| values.PARENT ||''', '''|| values.NAME ||''', '|| values.ENABLED ||')';
        end if;
    END LOOP;
END;
--...
```

I need this to export my Data and insert into an other Database by using sqlplus

thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with a hierarchical query if you want to insert static incrementing data (as per your original example):

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( id, parent, name, enabled )
  SELECT LEVEL, 't' || LEVEL, 'Test' || LEVEL, 1
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
```

If you want to build a query from an existing table then:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO table_name ( id, parent, name, enabled )'
       || LISTAGG( 
            'SELECT ' || id || ', '
                    || '''' || REPLACE( parent, '''', '''''' ) || ''', '
                    || '''' || REPLACE( name, '''', '''''' ) || ''', '
                    || enabled
            || ' FROM DUAL',
            ' UNION ALL '
          ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM )
FROM   table_name
```

If it is going to be longer than 4000 characters then you can generate multiple rows:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO table_name ( id, parent, name, enabled )' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SELECT ' || id || ', '
                 || '''' || REPLACE( parent, '''', '''''' ) || ''', '
                 || '''' || REPLACE( name, '''', '''''' ) || ''', '
                 || enabled
       || ' FROM DUAL'
       || CASE WHEN ROWNUM < COUNT(*) OVER () THEN ' UNION ALL ' END
FROM   table_name
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aee298e67b7834798b64d785f11d62e8)*

Or use the Oracle utilities `RMAN` or `ExpDP` to generate a backup of the table.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should stop reinventing the wheel. Oracle offers data pump export/import utilities which are designed for such a purpose - moving data around. In simple (or, should I say *most*) cases, you can even use the *original* export/import utilities.

You didn't specify database version you use so - here's 12c Data Pump documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-501A9908-BCC5-434C-8853-9A6096766B5A.htm#SUTIL2877

There are quite a few examples which will show *how* to do that. I'd suggest you not to skip reading documentation and jumping straight to running some code. You'd benefit in knowing what you're actually doing, instead of hoping that it'll turn *right*.

Answer (score 0):

One way is the usage of XML-Files for the data transfer.

Get the data as XML:

```
DECLARE
  l_xml        DBMS_XMLGEN.ctxHandle;
BEGIN
  l_xml := dbms_xmlgen.newContext('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID IN (... [inner select] ...)');
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_xmlgen.getXML(l_xml));
  dbms_xmlgen.closeContext(l_xml);
END;
```

Insert Statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (ID, PARENT, NAME, ENABLED)
SELECT dbms_xmlgen.convert(value(soc).EXTRACT('/ROW/ID/text()'     ).getStringVal(), 1)
     , dbms_xmlgen.convert(value(soc).EXTRACT('/ROW/PARENT/text()' ).getStringVal(), 1)
     , dbms_xmlgen.convert(value(soc).EXTRACT('/ROW/NAME/text()'   ).getStringVal(), 1)
     , dbms_xmlgen.convert(value(soc).EXTRACT('/ROW/ENABLED/text()').getStringVal(), 1)
  FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(EXTRACT(XMLType(<XML>), '/ROWSET/ROW'))) SOC
```